# How to resolve Zone Aware Promise in Ionic

Tags: angular9, capacitor, ionic5

I am using ionic5 with capacitor version 2.2.0. I am using capacitor network to detect if network is online or offline. But Network.getStatus() returns "Zone Aware Promise". Below is the code which i have tried.

Network Service

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
//import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { ErrorNotificationService } from '../service/error-notification.service';
import { errorMessages } from '../service/dao/errorMessageConstants';
import { TranslateConfigService } from './translate-config.service';
import { Plugins,NetworkStatus, PluginListenerHandle } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Network } = Plugins;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkService  {
  networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
  networkListener: PluginListenerHandle;

  constructor(private errorService:ErrorNotificationService) {
    this.listenToInternet();
  }
  

  listenToInternet(){
    this.networkListener = Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', (status) => {
      console.log("Network status changed", status);
      if(status && !status.connected){
        this.errorService.showTextErrorAlert(this.translateService.getTranslatedValue("messages.no_connection"))
      }
      this.networkStatus = status;
   });
  }

   checkNetworkPresent(){
    return Network.getStatus().then(network =>{
      console.log(network,"network as service")
     return network;
    })
  }
}
```

Since capacitor plugins returns promise, i am using "then" which executes after i get the network status. I am calling this method in below interceptor, but i am getting "Zone Aware Promise".

Http Interceptors

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NetworkService } from './network.service'
import { NEVER, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { LoaderService } from './loader.service'
import { ErrorNotificationService } from '../service/error-notification.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorsService implements HttpInterceptor {
  networkStatus : any;
  constructor(private networkService:NetworkService,private loader:LoaderService,private errorService:ErrorNotificationService) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
   
//here checknetworkPresent returns zone aware promise

    this.networkStatus = this.networkService.checkNetworkPresent();
    console.log(this.networkStatus,"Network")
    if(!this.networkStatus["connected"]){
     this.loader.hideLoader();
    // this.errorService.showTextErrorAlert("No Internet Connection")
     return throwError("no_connection");
    }else{
     return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

Am i going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The zone awareness issue is created when we ask Angular to perform some event/task which is something out of the "Angular Zone", all of this is done to make sure we have full control over the app.

NgZone is itself a very complex thing to understand at first. I'll suggest you to check out [this](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) out. You can create your own zones in Javascript.

Coming back to your issue.

So what is currently happening here is the call to the networkStatus plugin is blocked since it is performed outside of the NgZone.

In order to resolve your issue you need to:

1. inject ngZone in your NetworkService.
2. Wrap your piece of code around `run()` or `runTask()` method depending on your usecase.

So you need to do something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkService  {
  networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
  networkListener: PluginListenerHandle;

  constructor(
    private errorService:ErrorNotificationService,
    private ngZone: NgZone       // <~ 1. Inject ngZone 
   ) {
    this.listenToInternet();
  }
  

  listenToInternet(){
    this.networkListener = Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', (status) => {
      console.log("Network status changed", status);
      if(status && !status.connected){
        this.errorService.showTextErrorAlert(this.translateService.getTranslatedValue("messages.no_connection"))
      }
      this.networkStatus = status;
   });
  }

   checkNetworkPresent(){
    // 2. Wrap your code with `run` or `runTask` depending on your usecase
    this.ngZone.runTask(() => {
      return Network.getStatus().then(network =>{
      console.log(network,"network as service")
      return network;
    });
   });
  }
}
```

I hope this might help you.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will test this and let you know.

Comment: You are welcome. If it worked then please upvote the answer and mark it as correct answer so that it will be helpful for others who come across similar issue. :)

Comment: I get this zone awareness only first time I call the service. From next time I am getting normal output.